# iphone x UITable view top space

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x

I am building an app

the problem happen when I try to test my app on iPhone x , I found this space on the top of UITable View

[image]

Comment: You need to update your constraints, as I can see on the bottom it also shows a black bar.

Comment: @amira did you add splash screen for all iphone?

Comment: In Main.storyboard select the `View As:` at the bottom bar and select iPhone X. Then add constraints to it. It works much better that way!

Comment: @PiyushRathi I am already using constrain, but I do not know what is the problem here

Comment: @chiragshah yes I did add all sizes x, 2x, 3x

Comment: @TylerMiddleton ok I will try it and let you know, but will that affect other devices if I fix it on iPhonex

Comment: Have you added iPhone X splash screen? Constraint also need to set for iPhone X.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail no, it won't effect the other devices

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail there is no 2x and 3x image please look this [link](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/)